# Difference between numpy.linalg.solve() and R solve()

Tags: python, r, numpy

Teaching myself about GPs and Gaussian Regression i stumbled upon Nando's lectures on the subject  ([part 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4vGiHC35j9s) and [part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MfHKW5z-OOA)). So since my knowledge in python is limited, i tried to rewrite his [script](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~nando/540-2013/lectures/gp.py) in R. However, I am getting `NaN`when producing the standard deviation for the confidence intervals. After some more thorough examination of the problem, i discovered that the main difference lies in the `np.linalg.solve()` and R's `solve()`. So the question is, which is a suitable R solver for these kinds of operations?

**EDIT**

While trying to attack the issue, i found out that the results from the two pieces of code partially match when `solve(L, ker_x_x.test)` is replaced by `forwardsolve(L, ker_x_x.test)`. Still i cannot mimic the results from the original script.

**EDIT 2**

I have managed to match the results. In the Python version, matrix `Lk` is computed using `np.linalg.solve()` where in R script it should be `backsolve()`. To compute the `mu` vector ìn R, you should use the `forwardsolve()`.

Links to documentation:

- [numpy.linalg.solve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html)
- [R
  solve](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/solve.html)
- [R backsolve and
  forwardsolve](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/backsolve.html)

I provide my code for more comments:

```
# GPs Nando Style
# Simple GP Regression. Assumes a zero mean GP Prior.
# setwd("your directory")
# rm(list=ls())
# graphics.off()
# cat("\014")
# y <- 0.25*(x^2)

kernel <- function(sigma_f, l, x_i, x_j){
  val <- (sigma_f^2)*exp((-1*(t(x_i - x_j)%*%(x_i - x_j)))/(2*l^2))
  return(val)
}

N <- 10  # Number of training points
n <- 50  # Number of test points
s <- 10^(-5)

x <- runif(N, -5, 5)
y <- sin(0.9*x) + s*rnorm(N, mean = 0, sd = 1)  # f(X) is sin(0.9*x)


ker_x_x <- matrix(0, nrow = length(x), ncol = length(x))

for (i in 1:length(x)) {
  for (j in 1:length(x)) {
    ker_x_x[i, j] <- kernel(1, 0.1, x[i], x[j])
  }
}

L <- chol(ker_x_x + s*diag(N))

# points we are going to make predictions on
x_testSet <- seq(-5, 5, length.out = n)

# compute kernel
ker_x_x.test <- matrix(0, nrow = length(x), ncol = length(x_testSet))
for (i in 1:length(x)) {
  for (j in 1:length(x_testSet)) {
    ker_x_x.test[i, j] <- kernel(1, 0.1, x[i], x_testSet[j])
  }
}

# compute the mean at our test points
# Lk <- solve(L, ker_x_x.test)  # Issue was HERE!
Lk <- backsolve(L, ker_x_x.test, transpose = TRUE)
# mu <- t(Lk)%*%solve(L, y)  # Issue was here
mu <- t(Lk)%*%forwardsolve(L, y)

# compute variance at our test points
# compute kernel
ker_x.test_x.test <- matrix(0, nrow = length(x_testSet), ncol = 
length(x_testSet))
for (i in 1:length(x_testSet)) {
  for (j in 1:length(x_testSet)) {
    ker_x.test_x.test[i, j] <- kernel(1, 0.1, x_testSet[i], x_testSet[j])
  }
}

s2 <- diag(ker_x.test_x.test) - colSums(Lk^2)
s <- sqrt(s2)
```

Comment: Don't put code like `rm(list = ls())` into example - no one wants to copy and run your code and accidentally remove their work. Less severely, the `setwd`, `graphics.off` and `cat("\014")` are all unrelated to your problem and not worth including. I would delete all of it from your question. And your first meaningful line of code, `y <- 0.25*(x^2)`, throws an error because `x` isn't defined.

Comment: Now it is fixed

Comment: Without knowing much about R, i would expect those to be nearly 1:1 the same (matlab, python, R; all will the use the same code internally; except maybe for handling problems). Both are using LAPACK. Do some research (reading docs) to reason about this assumption and make sure you are using it correctly (including assumptions on the data!).