# How to port np.linalg.solve to R?

Tags: python, r, solver, blas

I'm trying to port some code from Python to R and I'm having a little trouble with a `numpy.linalg.solve` calculation.

Here is my Python calculation

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1.21320066609265e-09, 7.41796679861689e-10, 3.88326978297399e-09, -8.0434635935612e-12],
               [7.41796679861689e-10, 7.42222200630816e-09, -1.93295794328878e-09, -2.45873626472721e-10],
               [3.88326978297399e-09, -1.93295794328878e-09, 1.52225096683626e-08, 9.93308495566108e-11],
               [-8.0434635935612e-12, -2.45873626472721e-10, 9.93308495566108e-11, 1.27503537782411e-11]])

B = np.array([[4.87908846480423e-06, 5.95145387478624e-05, -2.52777639389024e-05, -8.97778789976655e-07],
               [3.78363029085449e-06, 6.06099965807516e-05, -2.41823065607605e-05, -1.99323696392639e-06],
               [3.78363029085449e-06, 6.06099965807516e-05, -2.41823065607605e-05, -1.99323696392639e-06],
               [2.29254385430977e-05, 3.54386564822562e-05, 6.04902019176734e-05, -9.56686605491086e-07],
               [2.29254385430977e-05, 3.54386564822562e-05, 6.04902019176734e-05, -9.56686605491086e-07]]).T

np.linalg.solve(A, B).T
Out[501]: 
array([[  3225.26,  15022.19,  -2128.05, 237883.89],
   [  4483.82,   7277.74,  -1814.67,    979.25],
   [  4483.82,   7277.74,  -1814.67,    979.25],
   [ 20073.38,   1939.59,   -777.31, -18911.1 ],
   [ 20073.38,   1939.59,   -777.31, -18911.1 ]])
```

In R, I create the equivalent matrices:

```
A <- as.matrix(structure(list(V1 = c(1.21320066609265e-09, 7.41796679861689e-10,
                  3.88326978297399e-09, -8.0434635935612e-12),
           V2 = c(7.41796679861689e-10, 7.42222200630816e-09,
                  -1.93295794328878e-09, -2.45873626472721e-10), 
           V3 = c(3.88326978297399e-09, -1.93295794328878e-09,
                  1.52225096683626e-08, 9.93308495566108e-11),
           V4 = c(-8.0434635935612e-12, -2.45873626472721e-10, 
                  9.93308495566108e-11, 1.27503537782411e-11)),
      class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L)))
B <- as.matrix(structure(list(V1 = c(4.87908846480423e-06, 5.95145387478624e-05, 
                  -2.52777639389024e-05, -8.97778789976655e-07),
                V2 = c(3.78363029085449e-06, 6.06099965807516e-05,
                       -2.41823065607605e-05, -1.99323696392639e-06),
                V3 = c(3.78363029085449e-06, 6.06099965807516e-05,
                       -2.41823065607605e-05, -1.99323696392639e-06),
                V4 = c(2.29254385430977e-05, 3.54386564822562e-05,
                       6.04902019176734e-05, -9.56686605491086e-07),
                V5 = c(2.29254385430977e-05, 3.54386564822562e-05,
                       6.04902019176734e-05, -9.56686605491086e-07)),
           class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L)))
```

From reading this post [Difference between numpy.linalg.solve() and R solve()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46853354/difference-between-numpy-linalg-solve-and-r-solve) I thought I should try backsolve:

```
> t(backsolve(A, B, transpose = TRUE))
      [,1]     [,2]       [,3]      [,4]
[1,]  4021.666 7616.490 -1719.3371 92393.246
[2,]  3118.718 7854.325 -1386.8310  7903.683
[3,]  3118.718 7854.325 -1386.8310  7903.683
[4,] 18896.658 2886.087  -480.3371 -3714.961
[5,] 18896.658 2886.087  -480.3371 -3714.961
```

...but these are clearly very different answers.

Edit: first getting cholesky decomp of A does not work either:

```
> t(backsolve(chol(A), B, transpose = FALSE))
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     [,4]
[1,]  842372.6 -185848.5 -230277.0 -1258487
[2,] 1870215.2 -412617.6 -511255.2 -2794078
[3,] 1870215.2 -412617.6 -511255.2 -2794078
[4,]  897618.3 -198038.6 -245379.0 -1341063
[5,]  897618.3 -198038.6 -245379.0 -1341063
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction here ?

Comment: From `?backsolve` : "Solves a triangular system of linear equations.". You don't seem to have this. Perhaps `?solve` but this returns an matrix singular error  (the determinant of A ~= 0 if that matters)

Comment: I got a different error with `solve()`:  `Error in solve.default(A, B) : 
  'b' (5 x 1) must be compatible with 'a' (4 x 4)`. I've also tried `t(backsolve(chol(A),B))` to no avail. FYI `numpy.linalg.solve` does not have this triangular restriction:(https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html) and uses LAPACK routine `_gesv`, but I've no idea how to find an R function which uses same LAPACK routine.

Comment: You need to pass matrices to `solve` ; e.g. use `solve(as.matrix(A), as.matrix(B))`

Comment: @user20650 - thanks now I'm getting the same error as you. I see in the helpfile that `solve()` also uses LAPACK routines DGESV and ZGESV, so now I'm more confused as to why `solve()` gives an error, but `numpy.linalg.solve` does not

Comment: Just read the error message: incompatible dimensions. It's not a problem in LAPACK, it'sa basic problem with how you built your matrix in the first place. You are trying to solve a near-singular system, passing a matrix with incorrect shape, and then you are blaming R? Get the maths right first.

Comment: Moved past that error already @Jean-ClaudeArbaut

Comment: So what is the problem now? If it's having different results, with a near-singular system it's not surprising. Don't expect to even have an answer. Get back to basics: where does this matrix come from? If it's structurally singular (and numerically only *near* singular), then it's nonsensical to try to solve the system.

Comment: Differences could the come from tiny details: compiler used to compile LAPACK, compilation options, or slight variations in the matrix because you copied as text. Your matrix may be what it is, but you shouldn't try to solve such a system. It's a problem with maths, not code. I have shown in the answer below an example that works as expected.

Comment: Besides, I just tried with a Fortran program calling LAPACK, and DGESV ends with an error because the matrix is exactly singular. Don't do that, period.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: you don't have to *port* this function, there is already the R [solve](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/solve.html) function, as well as many other ways, using for instance the Cholesky decomposition (for symmetric matrices), the QR decomposition, or functions from the [Matrix](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/00Index.html) package, which can handle, among others, sparse matrices.

---

As pointed out by user20650 in a comment below, you don't have the same data in R and Python. When the typo on A(3,4) is corrected, R detects the matrix A is singular and refuses to yield a result.

Here is the R code:

```
A <- matrix(c(1.21320066609265e-09, 7.41796679861689e-10, 3.88326978297399e-09, -8.0434635935612e-12,
              7.41796679861689e-10, 7.42222200630816e-09, -1.93295794328878e-09, -2.45873626472721e-10,
              3.88326978297399e-09, -1.93295794328878e-09, 1.52225096683626e-08, 9.93308495566108e-11,
              -8.0434635935612e-12, -2.45873626472721e-10, 9.93308495566108e-11, 1.27503537782411e-11),
            4, 4, byrow = T)

B <- matrix(c(4.87908846480423e-06, 5.95145387478624e-05, -2.52777639389024e-05, -8.97778789976655e-07,
              3.78363029085449e-06, 6.06099965807516e-05, -2.41823065607605e-05, -1.99323696392639e-06,
              3.78363029085449e-06, 6.06099965807516e-05, -2.41823065607605e-05, -1.99323696392639e-06,
              2.29254385430977e-05, 3.54386564822562e-05, 6.04902019176734e-05, -9.56686605491086e-07,
              2.29254385430977e-05, 3.54386564822562e-05, 6.04902019176734e-05, -9.56686605491086e-07),
            4, 5, byrow = F)

> solve(A, B)
Error in solve.default(A, B) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.46364e-17
Calls: solve -> solve.default
```

Note, however, that Python yields this for the [contition number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number) :

```
>>> np.linalg.cond(A)
5.955813150735809e+17
```

That is, the system is very ill-conditioned, i.e. the matrix is near-singular, and the result is highly sensitive to numerical errors. Even if Python and R both use LAPACK, tiny differences in how the library was compiled might explain why they don't yield the same result, or even that one fails and not the other. Especially since the LAPACK used by numpy was [apparently](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/main/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite) converted by f2py.
I don't get the same result either with [intel-numpy](https://pypi.org/project/intel-numpy/). And you might wonder why Intel Fortran with MKL doesn't yield the same as Intel Python with intel-numpy. Indeed, it's a bit surprising. And with a third version on Python/numpy (installed with MSYS2), I get yet another result.

With the Cholesky decomposition, R yields an answer (that isn't any more valuable, but anyway, it's an answer):

```
s <- chol(A)
backsolve(s, forwardsolve(t(s), B))
# or: backsolve(s, backsolve(s, B, transpose = T))

           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]        [,4]        [,5]
[1,]   8432.584  7593.700  7593.700  25745.1517  25745.1517
[2,]  13873.313  6591.618  6591.618    688.2458    688.2458
[3,]  -3551.561 -2664.813 -2664.813  -2327.7813  -2327.7813
[4,] 230104.178 -3666.895 -3666.895 -27384.6857 -27384.6857
```

---

A quick and dirty Fortran program to call LAPACK directly (Intel Fortran & MKL). The call to DGESV ends with error 3, i.e. the 3rd pivot is exactly zero, i.e. the matrix A is exactly singular, and it's really not a good idea to try to solve this system, whatever you are trying to "port".

```
program test
    implicit none
    real(8) :: a(4, 4), b(4, 5)
    integer :: ipiv(4), info, i
    
    a(1,:) = [1.21320066609266d-09, 7.41796679861689d-10, 3.88326978297399d-09, -8.0434635935612d-12]
    a(2,:) = [7.41796679861689d-10, 7.42222200630816d-09, -1.93295794328878d-09, -2.45873626472721d-10]
    a(2,:) = [3.88326978297399d-09, -1.93295794328878d-09, 1.52225096683626d-08, 9.93308495566108d-11]
    a(2,:) = [-8.0434635935612d-12, -2.45873626472721d-10, 9.93308495566108d-11, 1.27503537782411d-11]

    b = reshape([4.87908846480423d-06, 5.95145387478624d-05, -2.52777639389024d-05, -8.97778789976655d-07, &
                  3.78363029085449d-06, 6.06099965807516d-05, -2.41823065607605d-05, -1.99323696392639d-06, &
                  3.78363029085449d-06, 6.06099965807516d-05, -2.41823065607605d-05, -1.99323696392639d-06, &
                  2.29254385430977d-05, 3.54386564822562d-05, 6.04902019176734d-05, -9.56686605491086d-07, &
                  2.29254385430977d-05, 3.54386564822562d-05, 6.04902019176734d-05, -9.56686605491086d-07], &
                  [4, 5])

    call dgesv(4, 5, a, 4, ipiv, b, 4, info)
    print *, info
    do i = 1, 4
        print *, b(i,:)
    end do
end program
```

---

Let' have a look at a better-behaved example:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg
a = np.matrix([[2, 9, 4], [7, 5, 3], [6, 1, 8]], dtype=float)
b = np.eye(3)
np.linalg.solve(a, b)

array([[-0.10277778,  0.18888889, -0.01944444],
       [ 0.10555556,  0.02222222, -0.06111111],
       [ 0.06388889, -0.14444444,  0.14722222]])
```

While in R:

```
a <- matrix(c(2, 9, 4, 7, 5, 3, 6, 1, 8), 3, 3, byrow = T)
b <- diag(3)
solve(a, b)

            [,1]        [,2]        [,3]
[1,] -0.10277778  0.18888889 -0.01944444
[2,]  0.10555556  0.02222222 -0.06111111
[3,]  0.06388889 -0.14444444  0.14722222
```

Comment: @user20650  Good catch. But it's in the question.

Comment: Indeed good catch. I'll fix it in the question.

Comment: Just now saw your updated answer @Jean-Claude Arbaut - more useful thanks . About the maths aspect - I'm porting a function where arbitrary data could be fed in. Thus, if someone feeds in stupid data, and Python spits out wild numbers but doesn't error, but R errors, I need to understand deeply why, before writing a try-catch. I understand tiny details can change things, but if different languages calling same LAPACK routines on same CPU don't produce the same results, that sounds like a (possibly tiny) bug in one of the LAPACK version to me

Comment: @user2498193 Regarding the try/catch, yes it will be necessary. But it's already necessary in Python, as I get `numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: Singular matrix` in other cases. Now about the differences in LAPACK, note that a difference in how the code is optimized by the compiler may result in instruction reordering, hence tiny numerical differences, that are absolutely normal. With 5 differents compilations of LAPACK I got 5 different results, but it's not really a problem.

Comment: @user2498193 These differences can get huge when the matrix is ill-conditionned, but again, it's normal. It's up to the user to know the limitations of floating-point computations, and to know his own problem, and why he should care very much about not trying to solve a system that has anyway no solution (that a tiny numerical error gives the illusion that the problem has a solution is irrelevant).